# Getting Values from multiple divs and matching them to values of inputs

Tags: jquery

I was hoping you could help me out with this

http://jsfiddle.net/hyperlagete/z2LYb/2/

I have some HTML code from an exercise, and basically what i need to do is get the value of the numbers on each div, in this case "first-number" and "second-number" (with no IDs, all grouped by class), adding them up, and check if that addition is equal or different than the value typed on the input box by the user..
The HTML code i posted is for one case, i would have to do it for 10.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand what exactly it is you are trying to do, but maybe this will help you out somehow:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z2LYb/3/)

Comment: I'll try your solution. Basically what i'm trying to do is extracting values from 2 divs and checking is the addition of those values is the same result as the one typed by the user on the input box, so the function i'm trying to program should work when the input loses its focus.. Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm trying to generate 10 exercises to add and subtract numbers. The HTML code is already set, and via jquery i'm trying to replace the already set values that come in each div, with random numbers generated by a function.
So, i have 10 divs <div class='first-number'> and 10 divs <div class='second-number> 

The code here attempts to check the result of each input box when it loses the focus, and see if it matches the result of the numbers in each div.

I hope it's more understandable that way.

[http://jsfiddle.net/hyperlagete/z2LYb/2/][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/hyperlagete/z2LYb/2/